# How do I specify that my class be the owner of an object it creates?

Tags: delphi, ownership

I am trying to define a class that will have a public ADOConnection which another app can set.

However, I cannot get the constructor working to create the ADOConnection variable. This is the code I have so far:

```
unit SuperheroClass;

interface

uses
  ADODB;

type
  TSuperhero = Class

  private
    MyQry: TADOQuery;
    constructor Create;
  public
    MyCon: TADOConnection;

end;

implementation

constructor TSuperhero.Create;
begin
  MyCon := TADOConnection.Create(self);
end;

end.
```

If I am not mistaken, I need to create these internal class variables using Self so that they will belong to the class, and then I can free them in the class destructor.

This code gives me an error:

> [Error] SuperheroClass.pas(23): Incompatible types: 'TComponent' and 'TSuperhero'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could declare `TSuperhero = Class(TComponent)`.

A [`TComponent`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent.html) ancestor has the ability to own and manage other components

Also make sure that your `Constructor` is public if you want it visible to other units.
i.e.:

```
public 
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

...

constructor TSuperhero.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  // TSuperhero.Self now owns MyCon and responsible for freeing it
  MyCon := TADOConnection.Create(Self); 
end;
```

If `Superhero` is needed across the application, I would instantiate `TSuperhero` like:

```
Superhero := TSuperhero.Create(Application);
```

And let the `Application` be the owner of `Superhero` also responsible for freeing it.

---

Just to add to my answer, Your class `TSuperhero` usage is very much like a [`TDataModule`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TDataModule.html) (`TComponent`), so maybe you should really use a centralized [`TDataModule`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TDataModule.html) - drop a `TADOConnection` on it, and so on, and use that instance across your application.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense to me. I want to prevent against memory leaks myself.

Comment: I don't see any need to add additional overhead here. The connection can just be created using `nil` as the `Owner`, as long as code in the destructor also frees it. It's one additional line of code in the destructor, and also avoids memory leaks just as effectively by adding that single line of code.

Comment: @KenWhite, I thought the question was specific on how to *explicitly* create `MyCon := TADOConnection.Create(Self)` with `Self` as owner. This is also useful if you want to create `TSuperhero` with a Form as owner, and not worrying about manually freeing the instance.

Comment: I was reading this: " I need to create these internal class variables using self so that they will belong to the class, and then I can free them in the class destructor." There's either no need to use `Self` (which is proper if you don't need the additional functionality-and overhead-of TComponent) and use the destructor to free it, or use `TComponent` and `Self`, in which case there's no need for the destructor to free it. I don't see anything in the question that needs the additional overhead of `TComponent` at this point. (Note I did not downvote, but just commented.)

Comment: @KenWhite, After reading OP's question again (and again) I have asked him to un-accept my answer since I also believe that `TComponent` is not required. *personly* I would go for `TComponent` with `Application` as it's owner, simply because I prefer to do a `Superhero := TSuperhero.Create(Application)` on start-up, and forget about `Superhero`...

Comment: And also `TSuperhero` is kinda intended to be used very much like `TDataModule` (`TComponent)`. So maybe a `TDataModule` is the really correct way to go... :)

Comment: I never suggested deleting it (or even said it was wrong-as I said, I did not downvote it). I was just pointing out that there was no need to add design-time support, IDE integration, streaming, and COM support overhead if they're not needed here. (There's considerable overhead to adding TComponent; I prefer not to use it unless it's actually needed.

Comment: @kobik Your answer is what I wanted. I am not sure how to implement the class as a TDataModule though. And that would derive from TComponent as well so what would be the advantages? I want to stick to OOP as much as possible. Also, the user of this class will instantiate a TSuperhero object and then pass an ADOConnection to the object as a parameter. I hope this helps.

Comment: @user1685639, You don't need to "implement the class as a new TDataModule". You simply *use* a TDataModule. i.e: "File->New->Data Module". look [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TDataModule.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass nil as the parameter to TADOConnection.Create. This does not prevent you from destroying it in the TSuperHero class destructor.

```
constructor TSuperhero.Create;
begin
  MyCon := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
end;
```

The parameter passed to the TADOConnection constructor is used when the control is dropped onto a form as a visual component. You are getting the compile error in your code because TSuperHero does not descent from TComponent.

Comment: I added MyCon := TADOConnection.Create(nil); and there are no errors now.

Comment: Do I still have to declare TSuperhero from TComponent as suggested by kobik?

Comment: You can but there is no need to unless you need the extra functionality the TComponent brings you. If you do decide to go that way then you can use self in the parameter constructor as you did in your original question.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers to the questions you ask. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: If you create a component with .Create(nil) you should also free the object yourself if you don't need it anymore. Most likely in the destructor FreeAndNil(MyCon);

Comment: Only inherit from TComponent if you actually want to make it a component (i.e. something that you can drop on a form in the IDE). Otherwise don't be lazy and destroy what you created.

Comment: For a long time, I defended pov like yours. But after developing some components myself, I changed my ways: if I have to managa more than 1 (or max 2) subobjects, I inherit from TComponent even if it won't go to the pallete. If TObject or TPersistent had ownership I would certainly use it.